# How to create web pages for all resolutions (both mobile device and computer)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to write a small tool to convert pictures and text files to HTML pages.

The layout of my HTML page is quit simple:

[image: The layout of my HTML page]

The problem is, when I adjust the HTML page for computer browsers， the font is too small for mobile browsers.

When I adjust the the HTML page for mobile  browsers， the page is too ugly in computer browsers.

I do not know much about CSS. Is there any way to create a HTML page for all resolutions? or I have to generate two kinds of HTML pages, one for computer browsers and one for mobile browsers.

---

I talked about this problem with our UI designers. They told me, I have to use several css files + pictures with different size to do it. It seems that we were in the last century.

At last, I find this tool: [Pingendo](http://pingendo.com/), which is good enough for this HTML page.

Comment: You really need to try searching first - you mean "responsive design".

Comment: There are many css frame works, that can make your web page for available devices. "Bootstrap", "Foundation" etc.

Comment: @patricksweeney Thanks. Actually it is the first time I heard this word "Responsive Web Design".

Comment: @web2tips Thanks. I have heard "Bootstrap" lots of times. I will try it.

Comment: @neohope And that's fine - but simply searching for your title *on this site alone, let alone google* would probably turn up a bunch of results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is ["Responsive Web Design"](http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design/).

There are many paterns that are useful for this. The most important is this one:

```
@media all and (max-width: 1024px) { ... }
```

This is where you define different style sheets for different browser sizes. This way your site will cover smartphones, tablets and large desktops. Use a compact and cozy layout for smartphones and the usual layout for, say, a **min-width** of **1024px**.

As for touch optimization, you have to do that anyway. Nowadays, you can't publish a website with no touch optimization at all. But don't worry, this is the smaller portion of your problem as basic touch features doesn't require much customization at all.

Also you woult want to set the **viewport**. This is *very* important for mobile devices!

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd better talk about this with our UI designer first.